# Nginx permission denied to /home

Tags: nginx

I have nginx running and while I set location to `/data` or `/var/www/html` it works fine. However, when I set location to `/home/someuser` it says permission denied.

Can any one help me?

Comment: What are the current owner/group permissions on that folder?